# Docker --link not adding two entries to hosts file

Tags: docker

According to https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/, I can do the following:

```
$ sudo docker run -t -i --rm --link db:db training/webapp /bin/bash
root@aed84ee21bde:/opt/webapp# cat /etc/hosts
```

And there will be two entries in the /etc/hosts file for my link which I named `db`:

```
172.17.0.7  aed84ee21bde
. . .
172.17.0.5  db
```

However, when I run that, I only end up with a hosts file entry for the id and not the name.

Here is what I am trying:

```
$ sudo docker run -d --name ghost dockerfile/ghost
$ sudo docker run -d --name nginx -p 80:80 --link ghost:ghost dockerfile/nginx
```

This should give me two entries in `/etc/hosts` of the container I named nginx. However, when I run `` $ sudo cat `docker inspect --format '{{.HostsPath}}' nginx` `` all I get back is this:

```
172.17.0.2  da1afa360504

127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters
```

Shouldn't I be seeing an entry like `172.17.0.2  ghost` in there?

As far as I understand it, I am doing everything correctly. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark got me on the right track when he showed that he could create the link just fine. I checked my docker version with `$ docker version` and noticed that I was behind

```
Client version: 0.9.1
Go version (client): go1.2.1
Git commit (client): 3600720
Server version: 0.9.1
Git commit (server): 3600720
Go version (server): go1.2.1
Last stable version: 1.1.2, please update docker
```

I tried upgrading to the latest in Ubuntu, but that didn't work. To upgrade, I had to follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/472412/how-do-i-upgrade-docker which said to run the following:

```
$ wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c "echo deb http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
```

After that, I had the latest version and the linking worked!

Answer (score 2):

Works for me

## Example

Create a container

```
$ docker run -d --name container1 ubuntu sleep 1000
d4f1fe391b524d16154749f5e1d25fd340e4da8831440a5813bdb28bc5d63713
```

Run another linked container, printing out the hosts file

```
$ docker run -i -t --name container2 --link container1:container1 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
..
..
172.17.0.6  container1
```

An entry for "container1" is created.